# How can I display python code as a math formula?

Tags: python

How can I display python code as a math formula in the console application?

Example:

```
 a=1
 b=1
 c=1
 y=(pow(a,2)-2*b-pow(c,2))/(3*a*b)
```

[image]

Comment: In what? A web browser? A Tkinter environment? Electron? A LaTeX document? *Where* do you want to display it as a math formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) package is what you’re looking for. It can pretty print equations in the console. You’ll want to use the the [`preview`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.preview.preview) function to creat e.g. a PNG, which a browser can easily open or can be linked to in a HTML file— you’ll need to have LaTeX installed to do this.

Comment: Here’s the printing tutorial: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html#tutorial-printing